# jQuery UI : My resize function is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to know that my resize function is not working properly as I aspected means the problem is when I resize the div ( increase the padding ) and leave it and when I again try to resize it padding shrinks.

Note : I am Increasing the padding not the height.

```
$( function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
      resize: function( event, ui ) {
        var originalHeight = ui.originalSize.height;
        var newHeight = ui.size.height;
        var pad = 5;
        if (originalHeight < newHeight) {
          pad = newHeight - originalHeight;
        }
        $(this).css({'padding': pad, 'height': 200, 'width': 400});
      }
    });
 });
```

[My fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/6rh7emog/3/)

Comment: see if this works: https://jsfiddle.net/6rh7emog/4/

Comment: @JunaidAhmad I am sorry it didn`t work. On resizing second time it immediately decrease the padding. The problem is the same.

Comment: I think the problem comes from changing the padding. The way I see it, ui.originalSize.height gets the height property which in your case stays 200 no matter the padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah @Botimoo seems correct. You should probably consider positioning with something other than padding. But something like this probably is close to what you want if you want to stick with padding

https://jsfiddle.net/6rh7emog/5/

```
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
  </div>
```

```
$( function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
      aspectRatio: true,
      resize: function( event, ui ) {
        var originalHeight = ui.originalSize.height;
        var newHeight = ui.size.height;
        $('#wrapper').css({
              'padding': newHeight - 200 
        });
      }
    });
 });
```

Comment: one more thing how can I detect that which side of the div has been increased or decreased ( means the div has been resized from north side or south side how can I detect this )

Comment: the problem in your example is the padding the still 0px.

Comment: Did you check out the fiddle? From what I can tell from a visual perspective the padding is the same as your fiddle, the difference is I applied it to the wrapper instead of the resizeable element so the size does not snap back to the original size when you resize again.

For north/south side I thought the only resizeable parts are the right hand side and bottom side of the div. Not sure what you mean here - you should probably open another question if you want an answer to that.

Comment: I have checked the fiddle I have inspect element the wrapper and checked that the padding is not increasing. Listen what I really want is to increase or decrease the padding not the height.